# OpenOffice won't run

Tags: openoffice.org

I click the icon, the splash screen will come up, and then about half way, it will disappear, I can't get it to work at all, any possible solutions?? I tried to get Terminal output, but I couldn't seem to get anything

Comment: There wasn't *any* output in the terminal? We are going to need more information to have any idea on what the problem is.

Comment: Is there any OOo process running in the background?  (Have a look in the System Monitor.)

Comment: What should I run to get some output? And no, there isn't any other processes

Comment: Maybe reinstall all OOo packages (by Synaptic) ?

Answer (score 2):

Log as the guest user, to do this click on the shut-down icon on the right and in the menu that appears choose "Guest session". Try to start openoffice in this new session.

If it does start, then it's likely that your profile is corrupt. Get back to your real session (close the guest one with the shut-down menu). Click on your home on the Places menu, then on the View Menu select Show Hidden Files. Locate a directory called .openoffice.org, rename it to something different. Try to start OpenOffice again.

Note that you will lost all your settings for OpenOffice.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Monodevelop only about a week or so ago. It was caused by the permissions for the settings folder getting mutated (howsoever...) during a system update.

I had to delete the folder from the terminal (sudo) and then start it again.

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> `gksu openoffice.org` and see if it runs then. If it does, then it is permissions. (I guess you can also use `strace openoffice.org` to check for permission related errors).

You can:
**Either:** Just delete the settings folder (.openoffice.org) and restart openoffice and it'll work.

**Or:** Rename the settings folder to keep a backup just in case and then start openoffice. [see comments below]

Comment: I recommend to rename the folder .openoffice.org. If generating a new .openoffice.org folder didn't help, then you can easy set the folder back

Comment: That is a good point. However, I could afford to delete because 1) I was certain there was a permission error, 2) My installation was very new and didn't have much in terms of customization, 3) I was being able to run Monodevelop with sudo every time without fail which meant it _would_ create the folder if it wasn't found, considering it a "first run" situation (this is in fact what I tried to achieve).

Comment: It's a permission issue apparently, and now how do I fix thing... for good?

Comment: Either of the two ways I mentioned should let you run openoffice again. If by "fix for good" you mean stop this from happening again, then I don't think there's any way to do that as it seems to happen at random times for varying (apparent) reasons.

Comment: Well, as for now, it's being very constant, in the factor that it doesn't work :/

Comment: Have you tried running it with sudo?